# Best practices regarding setting properties on data objects in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am pulling data from an API, suppose the response looks like this

```
users: [{id: 1, name: 'Daft Punk'}, ...]
```

and I assign it to the vm by:

```
this.users = users;
```

Now, I show these users in a list and would like to toggle some state on a specific user, such as "visible" or "enabled" etc.

Currently I do this:

```
methods: {
    enableUser: function (user) {
        if (user.enabled === undefined) {
            Vue.set(user, 'enabled', false);
        }
        user.enabled= !user.enabled;
    }
}
```

I do the

```
if (user.enabled === undefined) {
    Vue.set(user, 'enabled', false);
}
```

part since the enabled property is not present in the response object from the API and I want to be able to use that property for v-show and similar things.

Is there a better way of assigning properties that should be reactive? Doesn't feel right writing that snippet for every custom property that I want to use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd probably `forEach` over the data and assign the additional properties before setting it on the view model:

```
// get data from api, then...
users.forEach(user => user.enabled=true)

this.users = users;
```

This will keep the rest of your code a lot cleaner - no need to check if the property is defined yet.

Comment: Thanks. Will think about this. Do you know of any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

so, you want to add a reactive property to all objects?
simplest way would be to make an adapter function
eg

```
//adapter function
function adaptToMyApp(externalObj)
{
    //add extra properties as desired
    externalObj.enabled = false;       
}

// fill users from api.
// and adapt them to your app.
users.forEach(user => adaptToMyApp(user))

// now use users as required
```